# How can I invoke a SOAP-XML WS with Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to invoke a SOAP WS using Ballerina, and the http:ClientConnector, how can I to pass the Body and parameters to the POST method?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [sample code of soapConnector.bal](https://github.com/ballerinalang/connectors/blob/v0.93/soap/src/org/wso2/ballerina/connectors/soap/soapConnector.bal) (version 0.93)

You need to construct a request XML payload like this

```
xml soapRequest = xmls:parse("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"" + namespace + "\"></soapenv:Envelope>");
```

and set payload along with headers in order to call the endpoint

```
    message backendServiceReq ={};
    string reqType = "application/soap+xml";
    string soapDefinition;
    soapDefinition, _ = (string) namespaceMap["1.2"];
    messages:setXmlPayload(backendServiceReq, soapRequest);
    messages:setHeader(backendServiceReq, "Content-Type", reqType);
    if (soapAction != "null") {
        messages:setHeader(backendServiceReq, "SOAPAction", soapAction);
    } 
   message response = httpConnector.post(url, backendServiceReq);
```

Comment: Hi Tharik, thanks for your response. I'm trying to use de soap conector setting the namespace, headers and payload, then I use:

`xml i1 = soap:constructSoapRequest(payload, namespace, headers);`

But I got the error: `httpsample.bal:14: undefined function 'soap:constructSoapRequest'`

Note: I import the following:

import ballerina.lang.system;
import ballerina.net.http;
import org.wso2.ballerina.connectors.soap;

Comment: can you confirm that the argument types are as per the expected of the particular function